# how to convert pandas Series of Numpy object into a Numpy matrix?

Tags: numpy, pandas, series

I find it hard to convert pandas Series of size `M` each containing a numpy arrays each of size `N` into a matrix/numpy array/dataframe of size `MxN`

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
d = pd.DataFrame({'grp': np.random.randint(1, 10, 1000), 'x':np.random.rand(1000,)})
s = d.groupby('grp')['x'].apply(lambda x: stats.gaussian_kde(x.values, bw_method = .01).evaluate(np.linspace(0,1,100)))
```

The output I get is of type Series where the type of the entries are numpy.ndarray.
How do I convert this to be size of 10 (groups) times 100 (evaluation bins)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.vstack` for that

```
sArray = np.vstack(s)
```

But in your case your `Series` is (9,100). If you want to make it (10,100) you need to change the line.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'grp': np.random.randint(1, 10, 1000), 'x':np.random.rand(1000,)})
```

to

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'grp': np.random.randint(0, 10, 1000), 'x':np.random.rand(1000,)})
```

or

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'grp': np.random.randint(1, 11, 1000), 'x':np.random.rand(1000,)})
```

Not sure what you want to do there.

Cheers